# Examples of linear regression models where one variable is continuous and one is categorical with more than two categories

Tags: regression, linear

I looking for examples where someone has graphed the results of a simple linear regression model where the dependent variable is continuous and the predictor variable is categorical with more than two categories.

For example, predicting mean temperatures from 3 different types of ovens.

I am finding plenty of graphed examples with two categories, but none with 3 or 4 categories. I would like to visually know what the model would look like on the data.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean the *dependent* variable is continuous?  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87487, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82557, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68847, or https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62756 for some examples.  Otherwise, could you describe your data more clearly?

Comment: @whuber see my edits. Yes the dependent variable is continuous.

Comment: Then it would seem any of the threads I referenced already answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

This [overview](http://r-statistics.co/Top50-Ggplot2-Visualizations-MasterList-R-Code.html) of visuals from ggplot shows several options:

- histograms
- density plots
- (Tufte styled)
- box plots
- violin plots

If it is all just about presenting the results/output of a regression model (predicted means, error, other calculated statistics, etc), and not an actual image of the raw data, then a table will be sufficient.

A quick example (just *one* out of the many variations!) using R and the referred package:

```
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x=Petal.Length,
                        fill=Species,
                        color=Species,
                        facet=Species)
      ) +
          geom_histogram(position="identity", alpha=0.5, bins=50) +
          geom_density(alpha=0.5) +
          scale_fill_manual(values=c("#009999", "#AAAAAA", "#999900")) +
          scale_color_manual(values=c("#009999", "#AAAAAA", "#999900"))
```

[image: multiple histogram example]

Comment: I am looking for a way to visually look at how well the model fits the data.

Comment: I have added a visual example. The model would be just the three averages, setosa ~ 1.462, versicolor ~ 4.260, virginica ~ 5.552 and you may do some anova or other statistical stuff to place a (modelled) number on setosa being more different from the other two.

Comment: The case of DependentContinuousVariable ~ IndependentFactorVariable is not so complex and the described graphs provide a good insight. In more complex models you could plot the residuals (which can be done in various way, but the idea/principle is the same every time).